# can't open mobile camera while using expo go app in android?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, camera

can't open mobile camera while using expo go app in android?
Camera is not open in **react native** expo app in android real device,
Incase I click button for open camera, It show some warning message.
But If I build apk, camera is open and working fine

```
    import {
  launchCameraAsync,
  useCameraPermissions,
  PermissionStatus,
} from 'expo-image-picker';
import { Alert, Button, View } from 'react-native';

const ImagePicker = () => {
  const [cameraPermissionInformation, requestPermission] =
    useCameraPermissions();

  const verifyPermission = async () => {
    console.log('PermissionStatus.DENIED', PermissionStatus.DENIED);
    if (cameraPermissionInformation.status === PermissionStatus.UNDETERMINED) {
      const responseStatus = await requestPermission();
      return responseStatus.granted;
    }
    if (cameraPermissionInformation.status === PermissionStatus.DENIED) {
      // Alert.alert(
      //   'Insufficient Camera Permission!',
      //   'This app need camera permission'
      // );
      const permissionResponse = await requestPermission();
      console.log(
        'permissionResponse.granted-----',
        permissionResponse.granted
      );
      return permissionResponse;
      // return false;
    }
    return true;
  };
  const imagePickerHandler = async () => {
    const hasPermission = await verifyPermission();
    console.log('hasPermission ', hasPermission);
    if (!hasPermission) {
      return;
    }
    const image = await launchCameraAsync({
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [16, 9],
      quality: 0.5,
    });
    // console.log(image);
  };
  return (
    <View>
      <View></View>
      <Button title='take picture' onPress={imagePickerHandler} />
    </View>
  );
};

export default ImagePicker;
```

[Warning Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYZI1.png)

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

- Clear the memory of your expo project. Run this

```
npx expo start --clear
```

**Solution 2**

- Simple but can make sense in some cases(like myself). Close your app and reload.

**Solution 3**

- My personal opinion is that, you might look to change your return statement in `if` statement in `imagePickerHandler`.
- That is try writing

```js
return <View/>
```

- You can also try implementing `useEffect` which makes things much more easier.
- For example, let me give a model code;

```js
useEffect(() => {
      (async() => {
          const cameraStatus = await Camera.requestCameraPermissionsAsync()
          setHasCameraPermission(cameraStatus.status === 'granted')})()},
          [])

      if (hasCameraPermission === null) {
          return <View/>
        }
      if (hasCameraPermission === false){
          return <Text>Enable access for Camera to proceed</Text>
        }
```